# How significant are hysteresis losses in iron wires with RF currents?

Tags: wire, hysteresis, loss

I understand that iron isn't a great choice of conductor for RF currents, as a wire dipole antenna for example. I understand there are several reasons, but I'm wondering specifically about one: hysteresis losses. How significant are hysteresis losses when an iron wire is a conductor, not part of a magnetic circuit? Can they be calculated? Are there any empirical data?

Comment: Hysteresis losses at RF? | Iron is liable to be a bad choice in many cases at most frequencies. You need to provide MUCH more detail to get a worthwhile answer and to not waste people's time. The question is "useful"  so I'll give you a +1 to offset the phantom downvoter BUT expect a few more downvotes if you don't improve the question.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Improve it how? *What* detail? If I knew what details were relevant, I would have included them. Maybe instead of bitching, you could enlighten me, or at least provide *constructive* bitching.

Comment: I've looked into this kind of stuff a couple years ago and you are unlikely to find actual empirical data on it for the simple reason: nobody uses it in this fashion because iron is such a strange material to use for RF frequencies. So there is very little if any empirical data. That being said, the majority of your losses are going to be skin effect losses and you are best off choosing very thin film waveguides for these kinds of 'bad' materials.

Comment: I wonder if it would be practical in your case to copper plate the iron wire. That would also make it solderable, if that matters. We have used copper-plated pure iron wire for quite different purposes, so I know the plating part is feasible and not crazy expensive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that's actually exactly what I was considering, but I wanted to explore the underlying reasons it works or does not work first. It's clear that skin effect would dictate most of the current would flow in the copper plating, but does the steel wire still interact with the current and associated fields? I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2):

I have doubts that hysterisis loss will count for much because most of the magnetic flux lines are around/outside the conductor and barely cutting through it. Yes, there is greater flux density up close to the wire but this is also the mechanism that makes skin conductivity (aka [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)\$^1\$) so bad in iron at any appreciable frequency and, because current travels at the surface of the iron, the flux lines will probably never be totally contained within the iron meaning there is a significant air gap and B will be low hence hysterisis loss will also be low.

\$^1\$ Quote from wiki -

> Skin depth also varies as the inverse square root of the permeability
>   of the conductor. In the case of iron, its conductivity is about 1/7
>   that of copper. However being ferromagnetic its permeability is about
>   10,000 times greater. This reduces the skin depth for iron to about
>   1/38 that of copper, about 220 micrometres at 60 Hz. Iron wire is thus
>   useless for A.C. power lines. The skin effect also reduces the
>   effective thickness of laminations in power transformers, increasing
>   their losses. Iron rods work well for direct-current (DC) welding but
>   it is impossible to use them at frequencies much higher than 60 Hz. At
>   a few kilohertz, the welding rod will glow red hot as current flows
>   through the greatly increased A.C. resistance resulting from the skin
>   effect, with relatively little power remaining for the arc itself.
>   Only non-magnetic rods can be used for high-frequency welding.